Straighten a Polygon into a line with Geopandas/Shapely
I'm using Python. geopandas and shapelly to process the geometries of a road intersection.
The geojson has a list of Polygons that I want to straighten into Lines, something like this:

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Is your question resolved? What should I do when someone answers my question?

The library pygeoops uses shapely under the hood to calculate a centerline of a polygon: pygeoops.centerline. It also supports geopandas GeoSeries as input.
You can use the parameters of centerline to finetune the removal of short branches, the simplify of the result,... to optimize the "cleaning" of the result.
Sample script:
import pygeoops
import shapely

poly = shapely.from_wkt("POLYGON ((0 0, 0 8, -2 10, 4 10, 2 8, 2 2, 10 2, 10 0, 0 0))")
centerline = pygeoops.centerline(poly)

# Centerlines for polygons in a geopandas GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame([{"name": "L-shape", "geometry": poly}], crs="epsg:31370")
gdf.geometry = pygeoops.centerline(gdf.geometry)

Result:

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of pygeoops

Hi @Pieter!
Great library you wrote, thanks for sharing! It really captured the centerline of the polygons.
The lines are not straight though, they have a bit of a zig-zag shape... Does the library has a feature to turn these centerlines into straight lines?
If not, no problem, I will try to write something to workout the lines generate by your library :)
Thanks again!

Normally you should be able to finetune this with parameters densify_distance and simplify_tolerance... e.g. like here: https://github.com/pygeoops/pygeoops/issues/86

Hi @Pieter! good day!
Using this params make the method "centerline()" either get stuck or execute really slowly...  Have you seen this behaviour?
But Im still able to get the centre lines when I don't use the parameter, I will try to come out with solution outside the "centerline()" to fizx the zig-zag lines.

densify_distance has indeed a big impact on the performance, so you need to be carefull with that parameter...

You can create rotated bounding geometries, extract and move one of the long rectangle sides to the center of the rectangle:
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import LineString
from shapely.affinity import translate 

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/centerline_polygons.shp")
df["rectangle"] = df.minimum_rotated_rectangle()
ax = df.plot(figsize=(15,15), color="lightgreen")
df.rectangle.boundary.plot(ax=ax, color="gray")


def moveline(dataframe):
    """A function to return a centerline of a polygon geometry"""
    rect = dataframe.rectangle
    rect_boundary = rect.boundary
    #Create a list of the minimum boundary rectangle sides
    line_segments = [LineString([pnt1, pnt2]) for pnt1, pnt2 
                      in zip(list(rect_boundary.coords[0::1]), list(rect_boundary.coords[1::1]))]
    line_segments.sort(key=lambda x: x.length) #Sort it by line length
    long_side_line = line_segments[-1] #Extract one of the long sides line
    #Extract its center coordinates
    line_center_x, line_center_y = long_side_line.centroid.x, long_side_line.centroid.y
    
    #Find the center coords of the bounding rectangle
    rect_centroid_x, rect_centroid_y = rect.centroid.x, rect.centroid.y
    
    #Move/shift the side line to the center of the bounding rectangle
    centered_line = translate(geom=long_side_line, xoff=rect_centroid_x-line_center_x, 
              yoff=rect_centroid_y-line_center_y)
    return centered_line

df["center_line"] = df.apply(lambda x: moveline(x), axis=1)
df["center_line"].plot(ax=ax, color="red", linewidth=5)


#Create a new dataframe using the center lines as geometry column and export to file
geo_col_name = df.active_geometry_name
df2 = df.set_geometry("center_line").drop(columns=[geo_col_name, "rectangle"]).rename_geometry("geometry").set_crs(df.crs)
df2.to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/centerline_polygons_centerlines.shp")

Result:

